# Refreshing Audio, Video, GIF & Iframe onclick Bootstrap pills and tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-4

```html
<head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-rwoIResjU2yc3z8GV/NPeZWAv56rSmLldC3R/AZzGRnGxQQKnKkoFVhFQhNUwEyJ" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-A7FZj7v+d/sdmMqp/nOQwliLvUsJfDHW+k9Omg/a/EheAdgtzNs3hpfag6Ed950n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tether/1.4.0/js/tether.min.js" integrity="sha384-DztdAPBWPRXSA/3eYEEUWrWCy7G5KFbe8fFjk5JAIxUYHKkDx6Qin1DkWx51bBrb" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-vBWWzlZJ8ea9aCX4pEW3rVHjgjt7zpkNpZk+02D9phzyeVkE+jo0ieGizqPLForn" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
    </head>
    
    <!-- Nav tabs -->
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" data-toggle="tab" href="#part1" role="tab">Part 1</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part2" role="tab">Part 2</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#part3" role="tab">Part 3</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    
    <!-- Tab panes -->
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="part1" role="tabpanel"><b>Story Part 1</b> <br> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ratione aliquam ab esse amet quam, alias commodi laboriosam nemo voluptates. Libero fuga, suscipit eos rem voluptatibus. Itaque sequi quaerat quidem doloribus. <br> BGM: <br><audio controls>
      <source src="https://freemusicarchive.org/music/listen/156afda13aef642c35b844c21681ad44002b8e88" type="audio/mpeg">
    </audio>
        </div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part2" role="tabpanel"><iframe width="100%" height="450" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/62576046&amp;auto_play=false&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false&amp;visual=true"></iframe></div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="part3" role="tabpanel"><iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/qycqF1CWcXg" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>
    </div>
```

How can i refresh each tab content when i move to another tab?
In my code here if i started the video or audio And moved to another tab, the video and audio will keep working, I want to refresh the entire tab, And if not possible, To refresh the entire tabs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a "tab" in one DOM element, I belive you can select it by Javascript, save its contents and place them back. Everything in that tab will literally stop existing for a moment.

Comment: an example please to understand it more.

Comment: When going to a new tab use something like `var tab = $("#TabToRefresh"); var val = tab.html(); tab.html(""); tab.html(val);`